# Select table rows with max value in property grouped by other property

Tags: spring, jpa

Im trying select the latest instances of the records in the single table grouped by task name.

Previously, the native @Query has been used but as the requirements grow, we decided to rewrite it into Specifications and JPA Criteria API.

Simple Specifications are clear, but I'm confused by creating Predicate selecting only the instance with the most recent scheduleTime

Any advice would be valuable, Thanks!

```sql
CREATE TABLE task
(
    id            text NOT NULL,
    applicationid text NOT NULL,
    taskname      VARCHAR(255),
    scheduletime  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

```java
@Query("SELECT t " +
            "  FROM Task t " +
            "  WHERE t.applicationId = :applicationId" +
            "    AND t.id NOT IN " +
            "    (SELECT t1.id " +
            "      FROM Task t1, Task t2 " +
            "      WHERE t1.applicationId = t2.applicationId " +
            "      AND t1.taskname = t2.taskname " +
            "      AND t1.scheduleTime < t2.scheduleTime)")
```

> Blockquote

Data:
+-------------------------------------------+
| id  applicationId  taskname  scheduletime |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1  app1  task1  2019-01-01 10:00          |
| 2  app1  task1  2019-01-01 10:20          |
| 3  app1  task2  2019-01-01 09:00          |
| 4  app1  task2  2019-01-01 09:20          |
+-------------------------------------------+

Should result in:
+-------------------------------------------+
| id  applicationId  taskname  scheduletime |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 2  app1  task1  2019-01-01 10:20          |
| 4  app1  task2  2019-01-01 09:20          |
+-------------------------------------------+

This code gives could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

```java
    public static Specification<Task> recent(boolean recent) {

        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            if (recent) {

                Subquery<Task> subquery = query.subquery(Task.class);

                Root<Task> subRoot1 = subquery.from(Task.class);
                Root<Task> subRoot2 = subquery.from(Task.class);

                subquery.select(subRoot1);
                subquery.where(cb.equal(subRoot2.get("applicationId"), subRoot1.get("applicationId")));
                subquery.where(cb.equal(subRoot2.get("taskname"), subRoot1.get("taskname")));
                subquery.where(cb.lessThan(subRoot1.get("scheduleTime"), subRoot2.get("scheduleTime")));

                return cb.in(subquery).not();
            }
            return cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true));
        };
    }
```

Comment: You are missing t1 join t2 thats for sure.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please show the native query?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I cant, have tried so many options I cant event remember much of them

Comment: @SimonMartinelli native query in issue description

Comment: @Antoniossss I thought it but still cant imagine how to incorporate join into the criteria

Comment: Critera API does have joins./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out how to do it. This code works:

```
 public static Specification<Task> recent(boolean recent) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            if (recent) {
                Subquery<Instant> subquery = query.subquery(Instant.class);
                Root<Task> subRoot = subquery.from(Task.class);
                subquery.select(builder.greatest(subRoot.<Instant>get("scheduleTime")));
                subquery.where(builder.equal(subRoot.get("applicationId"), root.get("applicationId")));
                subquery.where(builder.equal(subRoot.get("taskname"), root.get("taskname")));

                return builder.equal(root.get("scheduleTime"), subquery);
            } else {
                return builder.isTrue(builder.literal(true));
            }
        };
    }
```

The tricky part was to add `<Instant>` type to subRoot.get(). Otherwise dicky exception is thrown in build time